# Unable to find file after adding in Docker

Tags: docker

I am trying to use ADD to copy a zipped file locally to the container:

```
RUN mkdir /root/foo
ADD foo.zip /root/foo/
UNZIP -o /root/foo/foo.zip
```

I then build and run the container and enter into bash:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8080:8080 tomcat bash
```

When I go into the directory /root/foo/, the directory is not found. What should I be doing to create the directory in the container and view the contents of foo.zip?

Answer (score 1):

**Mount a host directory as a data volume**

In addition to creating a volume using the -v flag you can also mount a directory from your Docker daemon’s host into a container.

```
 $ docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

This command mounts the host directory, /src/webapp, into the container at /opt/webapp. If the path /opt/webapp already exists inside the container’s image, the /src/webapp mount overlays but does not remove the pre-existing content. Once the mount is removed, the content is accessible again. This is consistent with the expected behavior of the mount command.

The container-dir must always be an absolute path such as /src/docs. The host-dir can either be an absolute path or a name value. If you supply an absolute path for the host-dir, Docker bind-mounts to the path you specify. If you supply a name, Docker creates a named volume by that name.

A name value must start with start with an alphanumeric character, followed by a-z0-9, _ (underscore), . (period) or - (hyphen). An absolute path starts with a / (forward slash).

For example, you can specify either /foo or foo for a host-dir value. If you supply the /foo value, Docker creates a bind-mount. If you supply the foo specification, Docker creates a named volume.

If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Docker daemon has only limited access to your OS X or Windows filesystem. Docker Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (OS X) or C:\Users (Windows) directory. So, you can mount files or directories on OS X using.

```
 docker run -v /Users/<path>:/<container path> ...
```

On Windows, mount directories using:

```
 docker run -v /c/Users/<path>:/<container path> ...`
```

All other paths come from your virtual machine’s filesystem. For example, if you are using VirtualBox some other folder available for sharing, you need to do additional work. In the case of VirtualBox you need to make the host folder available as a shared folder in VirtualBox. Then, you can mount it using the Docker -v flag.

Mounting a host directory can be useful for testing. For example, you can mount source code inside a container. Then, change the source code and see its effect on the application in real time. The directory on the host must be specified as an absolute path and if the directory doesn’t exist Docker will automatically create it for you. This auto-creation of the host path has been deprecated.

Docker volumes default to mount in read-write mode, but you can also set it to be mounted read-only.

```
    $ docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/opt/webapp:ro training/webapp python app.py
```

Here we’ve mounted the same /src/webapp directory but we’ve added the ro option to specify that the mount should be read-only.

Because of limitations in the mount function, moving subdirectories within the host’s source directory can give access from the container to the host’s file system. This requires a malicious user with access to host and its mounted directory.

```
Note: The host directory is, by its nature, host-dependent. For this reason, you can’t mount a host directory from Dockerfile because built images should be portable. A host directory wouldn’t be available on all potential hosts.
```

Comment: I will give that a whirl and see what happens

Comment: That worked pretty well for mounting but I need to unzip the foo.zip. I have the command to unzip in the Dockerfile.. Why can't i see the contents of the zipped file?

Comment: You shud first unzip it into some dir , and then mount that dir with docker

Comment: What I am aiming to do is to add the zipped file into a container and then unzip the contents in that container.. Wouldn't unzipping it first be kind of counterproductive especially since I have a Run command that already unzips it?

Comment: I think mounting would not be the best option for what I am trying to achieve. Is there any other way I can do this..